# An easier way to print labels?

Tags: printer

We run an online web site where we sell groceries online. We get 30-40 orders a day and in each order we need to copy and paste the customers' addresses to the label printing software (Bartender) - but it takes so much effort because everytime you print an address you need to adjust the text so it fits to the label.

Our other option is to select the address text in the browser, then click "print selection". But this doesnt work because the text becomes too tiny if it fits in the label, or too big and half of it doesnt get printed.

Our label size is 4x6 cm. We can make it bigger if it's needed but it shouldn't be too big (as big as an A4) so that we can easily paste them on to the packages.

Do you know if there's an easier way to do this with a few clicks, and it'd be good if it looks good on the label as well.

Thank you all for any help in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that you are really looking for software.  Try posting on Software Recommendations